# Can I associate a file uploaded to a model with a session id for anonymous users in Django?

Tags: python, django

With my web app visitors should click a button which generates a unique video file - stores it in a model - and display it to them.

I'm having trouble understanding how to associate the video file with the visitor without making them sign in which I don't want to do.

Can I do this with sessions a bit like how a shopping cart works for guests?

```
models.py

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
import hashlib 
from hashid_field import HashidAutoField


class VideoUpload(models.Model):
    hashed_video_file_name = HashidAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True)
```

Comment: You could store their IP address. But if anonymous users are uploading these files, how exactly were you intending to track them?

Comment: You could do this using a cookie.

Comment: The videos are generated by a python script which is triggered by button click in the view.

Comment: Which approach would you take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this functionality by:

- a form that does a POST request when submitted
- a django view that generates the videofile triggered by the POST request,
- that view stores the hashed_video_file_name in a session after creating the video
- if the user revisits the page, check if a videofile exists for that hashed_video_file_name in the session

for example:

index.html

```
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'video-file' %}">
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>

    {% if video %}
       <video>
       // render video here
       </video>
    {% endif %}

</body>
```

urls.py

```
from views import VideoFileView

urlpatterns = [
    path('video-file/', VideoFileView.as_view(), name='video-file')
]
```

views.py

```
from models import VideoUpload
from video_generator import generate_video_file

class VideoFileView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        context = {}

        try:
            hashed_video_file_name = request.session['video_file']
            video_upload = VideoUpload.objects.get(hashed_video_file_name=hashed_video_file_name)
            context = {
                'video': video_upload.videofile
            }
        except KeyError, VideoUpload.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    #   this html also contains form
        return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)

    def post(self, request):
        # here your magic to generate video_file
        video_file = generate_video_file()

        video_upload = VideoUpload.objects.create(videofile=video_file, name='name')
        request.session['video_file'] = video_upload.hashed_video_file_name
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'video': video_upload.videofile})
```

Comment: Thank you! I am studying this and trying to adapt for my existing (messy) code. First time using class based views. The `video_generator` module is just an example name yes?

Comment: Yes, thats an example name to illustrate you might need to import the generate_video_file() method. That method is also an example.

Comment: Not sure how to bring my existing view functions (showvideo and video_upload_detail_page) into VideoFileView. Added code to question for context. It is possible? Sorry for the messy code - was adapted from this tutorial and not sure how to get rid of the front end form part (which I dont need) without breaking things yet -http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-create-a-video-uploader-with-Python-in-Django.php. Hope to tidy up as I understand better.

Comment: @flexkwando You now added a VideoUpload form while before you always say 'generates a unique video file '. Does the user upload a video or do you create it for them?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I create the video for them as before. The video upload form is because I didn't know how to upload a video to a model without a form so I used this method. I don't want the video upload form part but it's tangled into my code at the momemt.

Comment: I now understand that for this method I don't need my existing view functions (showvideo and video_upload_detail_page). What I need to do is bring the python script that generates the videofile into  VideoFileView(View). Currently this is a separate python script that I simply imported into the Django project. I will learn about how to adapt this and bring it into the view now.

Comment: @flexkwando you can import your python script that generates the videofile like I wrote 'from video_generator import generate_video_file' as an example. After importing you can use it in the view depending on your needs.

Comment: thanks. I set everything up and when I click 'submit' the python script runs and makes a video. If I check in admin I can see the video in there. However, I get this error when the 'video-file' page opens. `Exception Type: AttributeError at /video-file/
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute '_committed'`. What does it mean and how can I solve it? I will add the traceback call to my question.

Comment: It looks like a mistake with the generated video file. Make sure var video_file when creating the VideoUpload object is the file itself

Comment: I tried like this video_file = 'outx.mp4' and error is now:
Object of type Hashid is not JSON serializable

Comment: I changed to `video_file = 'videos/outx.mp4'` and I removed the hash id element from the model, storing name in a session instead. All working nicely.

Comment: Yes works well and solves my problem - thanks for the help!